# Loading files in Whitebox GeoSpatial

Tags: file-geodatabase, file-formats, whitebox-gat

I just discovered Whitebox geospatial but cannot figure out how to load or open a shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Click the "Add Layers" button, browse to your shapefile, select it and click "Ok".

[image]